# Making tooltip move with slider handle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to make a slider where a tooltip will appear above the slider handle indicating the slider value.

I got it almost working but it's weird how it updates.  It only moves to the slider handle occasionally.

Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  var slider = $('#slider');
  slider.tooltip({
   position: {my: "center",
              at: "top-100%",
              of: ".ui-slider-handle"}
  });
  slider.slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      slider.tooltip( "destroy" );
      slider.tooltip({
        content: ui.value.toString(),
        position: {my: "center",
                  at: "top-100%",
                  of: ".ui-slider-handle"}
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#slider{
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="slider" title="0">

</div>
```

Why does the position only lock to the slider infrequently and not on every value change?

Edit:  added destroy and now it is closer to being how it should be but still not quite there as I don't want it to dissapear, just update.

Comment: The tooltip is configured to show at the top of `ui-slider-handle` but tooltips are triggered by the [mouseover event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover), not the [mousedown event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousedown). So, when you hover over the slider the tooltip shows there but it will not show as you drag it. You might want to try the [`track` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-track) for the tooltip configuration.

Comment: tried setting slider on handle and enabling track but no joy.  I guess I have to manually trigger the tooltip event